# Gnome 3.12 logout button gone from menu

Tags: 14.04, gnome, menu, lock-screen, logout

Logout entry from gnome menu has disappeared all of a sudden. How can I get it back? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64Bit wit Gnome 3.12